# QRegExp For QSortFilterProxyModel - Find All Items In A List

Tags: python, regex, qt, qregexp, qsortfilterproxymodel

Am using PyQt & getting stuck on using setFilterRegExp() with a QSortFilterProxyModel.  The source model outputs integers 1-30, and the QSFPM is to filter 1-30, leaving only the numbers in a supplied list.

```
proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp('^%s{1,1}%' % sourceModel.wantedNumbersList()))
```

If manually entering the desired numbers:

```
proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp('^[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 18, 19]{1,1}%'))
```

both result in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9] being left.  The desired numbers >=10 aren't left in the results, and 1 is included for some reason.

Also tried:

```
proxy.setFilterRegExp(RegExp('^[2|3|4|15]{1,1}$')))
```

..which gave [1,2,3,4,5] i.e. interpreted the desired number 15 as 1 & 5.

From the docs, I thought ^ & $ would find exact matches of each, but instead finds all occurrences of all numbers.

Many Regards

Comment: can you provide a sample input and your desired output?

Comment: Hi Fede.  Have rewritten the question.  Feels I've supplied the requested info, without copying in the full QSqlTableModel classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that character classes treat characters inside them as individual characters, unless when using a range. So, what:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 18, 19]
```

Will match is: `2`, `,`, , `3`, `,` (again), [...], `1`, `9`, `,` (again), , `1` (again), etc.

What the regex has to look like is actually:

```
proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp('^(2|3|4|5|8|9|10|18|19)$'))
```

Or shortened as much as possible:

```
proxy.setFilterRegExp(QRegExp('^([234589]|1[089])$'))
```

I guess you will have to change how `sourceModel.wantedNumbersList()` appears (some string manipulations) or input it manually.

If you do it via string manipulation, I would suggest stripping the square brackets and replace the comma followed by space by a pipe `|`, then use `'^(%s)$'` for regex.

Comment: Hey @Jerry.  Many thanks, this works perfectly.  A new function now takes the original list & converts it to the string (2|3|4|5|8|9|10|18|19), via 'newL = "|".join([str(t) for t in self.originalIntegerList()]); return "("+newL+")"'.  The QSFPM's QRegExp is now '"^%s$" % self.listAsStringForRegExp()'.

Comment: @user2422819 You're welcome :) And I noticed I used the `%` sign in my regex instead of `$`, my bad.